# Connect WHERE clause to link

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, where-clause

I need to connect a WHERE clause to a link. Here is my code:

```
<body>
<?php

function toiletPaper($input) {
    // Clean input
    return $input;
}


$username="USERNAME";
$password="PASSWORD";
$database="DATABASE";

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query="SELECT * FROM searchacts";
$result=mysql_query($query);

// process form when posted 
$query = "SELECT * FROM searchacts";
$options['PriceLow'] = array("desc" => "Price (Low to High)","query" => " ORDER BY price ASC");
$options['PriceHigh'] = array("desc" => "Price (High to Low)","query" => " ORDER BY price DESC");
$options['NameAZ'] = array("desc" => "Name (A-Z)","query" => " ORDER BY name ASC");
$options['NameZA'] = array("desc" => "Name (Z-A)","query" => " ORDER BY name DESC");

$query = "SELECT * FROM searchacts";
$filter['partybands'] = array("desc" => "Party Bands","query" => " WHERE category='Party Bands'");


// Important: function name is made up
$cleanValue = toiletPaper($_REQUEST['value']);
if (array_key_exists($cleanValue, $options)) {
    $query .= $query.$options[$cleanValue];
}
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."'>All</a>";
foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
    echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?value=".$key."'>".$value['desc']."</a>";

}   


?>

<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='post' name='form_filter' >  
    <select name="value">  
        <option value="all">All</option>  
        <option value="PriceLow">Price (Low to High)</option>  
        <option value="PriceHigh">Price (High to Low)</option>  
        <option value="NameAZ">Name (A-Z)</option>  
        <option value="NameZA">Name (Z-A)</option>  
    </select>  
    <br />  
    <input type='submit' value = 'Re-Order'>  
</form>

<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$image=mysql_result($result,$i,"image");
$name=mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
$category=mysql_result($result,$i,"category");
$description=mysql_result($result,$i,"description");
$stamps=mysql_result($result,$i,"stamps");
$stickmen=mysql_result($result,$i,"stickmen");
$price=mysql_result($result,$i,"price");
$view=mysql_result($result,$i,"view");
$actpagelink=mysql_result($result,$i,"actpagelink");


?>


<a href="<?php echo $actpagelink; ?>" class="searchitem">
<div class="searchimage"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"/></div>
<div class="searchtext">
  <div class="searchname"><?php echo $name; ?></div>
  <div class="searchcategory"><?php echo $category; ?></div>
  <div class="searchdescription"><?php echo $description; ?></div>
</div>
<div class="searchstamps"><img src="<?php echo $stamps; ?>" /></div>
<div class="searchstickmen"><img src="<?php echo $stickmen; ?>" /></div>
<div class="searchprice"><span class="pricefrom">from</span>&pound;<?php echo $price; ?></div>

<div class="searchview"><img src="<?php echo $view; ?>" /></div>


</a>

<?php
$i++;
}


mysql_close();
?>


</body>
```

So I have my clause:

```
elseif($_POST['value'] == 'partybands') {   

            $query = "SELECT * FROM searchacts
    WHERE category='Party Bands'";   
        }
```

Which I need to connect to a link eg. `<a href="">Party Bands</a>`

How can I do that as I will have quite a lot of where clauses to filter the data.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.  Are you asking for a way to do that that cuts down on repetition?

Comment: Also be aware that mysql_connect is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: Sorry, I need it so that when the link is clicked it activates the WHERE clause as I will have quite a few of them

Comment: We don't know which your output variable for that Party Bands query is, so cannot provide you with the according `echo` command. Besides this sounds awfully trivial. Please try first, then ask for help with more specific elaboration on your problem. -- Hint: you can reduce some code with an array map for the queries: `$queries = array("partybands" => "SELECT * FROM searchacts WHERE category='Party Bands'", "NameZA" => "SELECT * FROM searchacts ORDER BY name DESC", ...);` and then using `mysql_query($queries[ $_POST["value"] ]);`. Besides, consider something less dated, like PDO for convenience

Comment: I tried putting the the queries in an array map like you suggested but it just stopped working. I've tried this: `elseif($_REQUEST['value'] == 'partybands') {   
        
        $query = "SELECT * FROM searchacts
WHERE category='Party Bands'";   
    }` with this: `<a href="<?php echo $_REQUEST["partybands"]; ?>">Party bands</a>` which isn't working either

Comment: That is because you are doing it wrong... please read my link below on arrays... pay special attention to associative arrays

Comment: Ok so now i've got this: `$filter=array("partybands"=>"SELECT * FROM searchacts
WHERE category='Party Bands'");

if (in_array("partybands",$filter))` but can't work out how i would connect it t a link. As you can tell I'm new to php so bear with me!!

Comment: what do you mean by "connect to a link"? Do you need to replace the select by links?

Comment: Urhmm. Can I post links on here so i can show where i'm testing it to make it more clear?

Comment: I meant so when a link is clicked it activates the WHERE clause. Here is where I'm testing it: http://tinyurl.com/aue2hhy So you can see there is a link at the top called 'Party Bands' just abouve the first div

Comment: oooooooooooooooooook... so you want to replace the dropdown with links?? for that you need to listen to AllInOne's advice... change the $_POST for $_REQUEST and then you can use the full URL like he used in his example.

Answer (score 0):

Use url parameters and pass in variables, then use those variables to trigger what you want the where clause to say.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an associative [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to validate.

Also make sure you sanitize the input before you use it.

EDIT2:

```
<body>
<?php
function toiletPaper($input) {
    // Clean input
    return $input;
}

$username="USERNAME";
$password="PASSWORD";
$database="DATABASE";

mysqli_connect("localhost",$username,$password);
@mysqli_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

// process form when posted
$query = "SELECT * FROM searchacts";
$options['partybands'] = array("desc" => "Party Bands","query" => " WHERE category='Party Bands'");
$options['PriceLow'] = array("desc" => "Price (Low to High)","query" => " ORDER BY price ASC");
$options['PriceHigh'] = array("desc" => "Price (High to Low)","query" => " ORDER BY price DESC");
$options['NameAZ'] = array("desc" => "Name (A-Z)","query" => " ORDER BY name ASC");
$options['NameZA'] = array("desc" => "Name (Z-A)","query" => " ORDER BY name DESC");

// Important: function name is made up
$cleanValue = toiletPaper($_REQUEST['value']);
if (array_key_exists($cleanValue, $options)) {
    $query .= $query.$options[$cleanValue];
}
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."'>All</a>";
foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
    echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?value=".$key."'>".$value['desc']."</a>";
}
?>
<br />
<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
    $image = mysqli_result($result,$i,"image");
    $name = mysqli_result($result,$i,"name");
    $category = mysqli_result($result,$i,"category");
    $description = mysqli_result($result,$i,"description");
    $stamps = mysqli_result($result,$i,"stamps");
    $stickmen = mysqli_result($result,$i,"stickmen");
    $price = mysqli_result($result,$i,"price");
    $view = mysqli_result($result,$i,"view");
    $actpagelink = mysqli_result($result,$i,"actpagelink");
?>

<a href="<?php echo $actpagelink; ?>" class="searchitem">
    <div class="searchimage"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"/></div>
    <div class="searchtext">
        <div class="searchname"><?php echo $name; ?></div>
        <div class="searchcategory"><?php echo $category; ?></div>
        <div class="searchdescription"><?php echo $description; ?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="searchstamps"><img src="<?php echo $stamps; ?>" /></div>
    <div class="searchstickmen"><img src="<?php echo $stickmen; ?>" /></div>
    <div class="searchprice"><span class="pricefrom">from</span>&pound;<?php echo $price; ?></div>
    <div class="searchview"><img src="<?php echo $view; ?>" /></div>
</a>

<?php
 $i++;
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: or [array_key_exists](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

Comment: Edit2: Not tested... just to give you an idea on how to do the Links

Comment: Ok, I actually want to keep the dropdown for low - high, a-z etc and wanted to filter categories with links. Ok so I've tried the above and its not even connecting to the db anymore, i've noticed you changed it to mysqli, could it be that do you think? Thanks for taking the time to help by the way! Much appreciated

Comment: maybe, you can try to remove the "i"s... As I said, I did not test it. As for what you want to do, You can check my example and mix it with yours and you will be able to do what you want. Just have 2 different variables for sort and filter.

Comment: Ok, i've edited my code above. I'm now getting the error: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/enterta1/public_html/searchtestingv1.php on line 39

Comment: Ok, I cant get it to work. Reverting back to my old code i'm trying this which also isn't working: `if($_REQUEST['value'] == 'partybands') {   
        
        $query = "SELECT * FROM searchacts
WHERE category='partybands'";   
    }` with a link with: ?value=partybands on the end

Comment: Oh no wait its working now i put category='partybands' instead of 'Party Bands' :S

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are trying:

http://example.com/yourscript.php?value=partybands

But finding that that does not work...

This is because you are looking for the variable `value` in the `$_POST` array.

```
$_POST['value'] == 'partybands'
```

If you want to be able to grab the value from either POST or GET you can use $_REQUEST

```
$_REQUEST['value'] == 'partybands'
```

You'll also need to modify the topmost conditional `isset()`.

But do take seriously the cautions that others have made here with regards to security and forward compatibility.

Do not trust user data.  Must be sanitized.  Best way to accomplish is probably through PDO.

Comment: He does have post as the form method, but I do agree that REQUEST could be used for testing purposes.

Comment: @Manatax I took the question to mean he wanted help getting this to work: <a href="">Party Bands</a>.  For that he probably wants a GET.